# jQuery UI multiple Datepickers: set individual event by id after setting options by class

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, onselect

I have multiple datepickers in one page.
I user class name to set the option for things like appears.

```
$('.datepickers').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        showWeek: true
});
```

Then, I want to set onSelect event for two of them.

```
$('#to').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        $('#from').datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
```

Similar onSelect event setting for others.

However, this would not work. Any suggestion for how to fix this, besides setting all options individually by id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try the following syntax? You don't want to _init the datepicker widget again. You just want to change an option. This is the way to do that with jquery ui widgets.

```
    $('#to').datepicker('option', 'onSelect', function(selectedDate) {
            $('#from').datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        });
```

Comment: it works. I original throught onSelect is an event, so I could not use this method. I have tried $('#to').datepicker('event', 'onSelect'..., and obviously it does not work.

Comment: If you want to add/change multiple options in one go, use `$('#from').datepicker("option", { minDate: selectedDate, defaultDate: selectedDate});`

Answer (score 1):

i created a functional demo here to show a possible solution:

### [click for the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/Apqnc/)

you don't have to create multiple datepicker methods.  just use the "onSelect" method to:

1. test whether the current datepicker has "#to"
2. if so, use the "dateText" value from this datepicker to intialize the "#from" datepicker
3. use the current "inst" value to traverse the dom to the "#from" datepicker and set it's value.

these were the key lines:

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
   if(inst.id === 'to'){
     $('.datepickers').filter($('input#from')).datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
  }          
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I only choose the other answer is because I do not like to call the if statement everytime one of the datepickers is onSelect